# What skills to learn for web development?

Tags: website-design, resource-recommendations

I'm a new enthusiast of web programming/development. Recently I started lectures and started studying to learn web development. I don't know if this forum is the right place to find help, but I wish to learn enough to be able to achieve designs like [this](http://slaveryfootprint.org/).

Could you recommend me some adequate resources?

Comment: jquery, javascript, CSS and HTML.

Comment: This _is_ the right forum for asking questions, however we concentrate on the design aspect of things and here at GD.SE we answer specific questions that have a clear answer and are applicable to a wider audience. As it stands your question is too broad and complex to be answered in our typical Q&A format. If you have a specific question about certain techniques or design principles feel free to ask another question.

Answer (score 2):

**Web Design** is a ***mix*** of:

**Design** - Photoshop/Illustrator & **Programming** - HTML/CSS/JavaScript etc.

If you're focused on building things that work, **learn the foundation languages** of HTML & CSS first.

Design is the paint to finish the job.
Good Luck.